# Could not find rugged-0.24.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, gitlab

I got an error when Installing gitlab on Centos 6.7 from source code.

[image: error and gem status]

My ruby version is 2.1.0 ,gem version is 2.2.5 .

How can I install rugged-0.24.0 ?

Thank you first.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ruby.taobao.org` as your gem source, it hasn't have `rugged` version yet. To install rugged v 0.24 you can do any of these:

a) Update `ruby.taobao.org` or ask whoever can update it

b) User official gem source, i.e. put: `source 'https://rubygems.org'` in your Gemfile

Comment: Thank you very much . I can't visit  "https://rubygems.org" because of the government.But I'd found a new image 'https://gems.ruby-china.org' instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. reason:We can not visit https://rubygems.org
2. Unfortunately , 'https://ruby.taobao.org' which had served serval years didn’t update recently。
3. https://gems.ruby-china.org now is on service.